# FTP connection java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to upload the file to a server. What is the way for uploading a file to a server through FTP?

i wrote this class:

serverconnect.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;


public class serverconnection
{

    public FTPClient connectftp() 
    {
        FTPClient ftp = null;
        try {
            ftp.connect("ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/");
            ftp.login("zule", "*****");
        //  ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/public");
        //  ftp.makeDirectory("200");
        } catch (SocketException en) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            en.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ftp;
    }
}
```

and this is the mainActivity ( only the relevant code):

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button scan;
    String contents;
    String format;
    TextView contentstext;
    TextView formattext;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //----------------------FTP-------------
        serverconnection ftpconnect =new serverconnection();
        FTPClient ftp=ftpconnect.connectftp();
        scan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
        .....
```

and when i install the app on my phone i get an error: "unfortanly your app must stopp..."

the new code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button scan;
    String contents;
    String format;
    TextView contentstext;
    TextView formattext;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //----------------------FTP-------------
        //serverconnection ftpconnect =new serverconnection();
        //SimpleFTP ftp=ftpconnect.connectftp();
        SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
        try {
            ftp.connect("market.bugs3.com", 21, "u884282808", "lionetwork1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the new logcat:

```
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.market/com.example.market.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:108)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP.connect(SimpleFTP.java:68)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.example.market.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-16 13:43:31.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: i dont have a stack traces because i am not running the app on the emulator because it hasnt an internet connection..maybe someone see the problem with this code? (i know that the problem is the ftp)

Comment: thanks, i add this check to my code, however it still didnt solve my problem

Comment: @ Reimeus , i add the "commons-net-2.0.jar" and  "commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar", it is matter which version? 1.4.1 or 2.0?

Comment: i added the "commons-net-1.4.1.jar" and removed  "commons-net-2.0.jar" and "commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar" and i have the same problem: "unfortunely your app stopped...", someone has another solution?

Comment: i added the updated logcat after removing  "commons-net-2.0.jar" and "commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar" and adding external jar: ""commons-net-1.4.1.jar"..hope it help to understand the problem

Comment: i added the new code that i use with simpleFTP and it solved the problem that it doesnt recognize the import FTP:

however i uploaded the new logcat with a new problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: `AsyncTask` class was deprecated in API level 30. Please use [`java.util.concurrent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) instead.**

The problem is the fact that you're trying to make a network call on your main thread. Which is not allowed on Android 3.0 or higher.

You should solve this by calling the FTP server on a different thread. A good way to do this is to use AsyncTask:

```
private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPClient> {
     protected FTPClient doInBackground(Void... args) {
        serverconnection ftpconnect =new serverconnection();
        FTPClient ftp=ftpconnect.connectftp();
        return ftp;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(FTPClient result) {
         Log.v("FTPTask","FTP connection complete");
         ftpClient = result;
         //Where ftpClient is a instance variable in the main activity
     }
 }
```

Then you can run this background thread using the following code in the main thread:

```
new FtpTask().execute();
```

EDIT:

If you want to pass parameters between the different methods, you can change the
`AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` superclass initialization.

For example `AsyncTask<String, Double, Integer>` will make it possible to pass a String variable to the doInBackground method, keep track of progress using a double and use a integer as the result type(the result type is the return type of doInBackground, which will be sent to onPostExecute as a parameter).

Comment: thanks for answer, i created a new task called: "FtpTask" with the code that you wrote...however it wrote to me this error: "The type FtpTask must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void...)", how can i solve it?

Comment: thanks alot!!,the app work for me without throw an error...however one change that i needed to do is to delete the private from "private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask" also how can i recieve the ftp from "new FtpTask().execute();"?  thanks again

Comment: You can do this by setting the result type of the FtpTask class to FTPClient like this: `AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPClient>`. Then in the onPostExecute you can return it to your main activity. (Preferably by making the FtpTask an inner class of the main activity, so it can access the main activity's fields and properties)

Comment: i didnt understand you...can you edit your answer with the updated functions?thanks in advance

Comment: hi, i edited my MainActivity to be: "SimpleFTP ftpclient=newFtpTask().execute();" and in the FtpTask.java i changed to : "protected void onPostExecute(FTPClient result) {
        Log.v("FTPTask","FTP connection complete");
        ftpclient = result;
    }" however the ftpclient is not recognized in the FtpTask.java file so it says the i need to create an FtpClient local vairable,i am not sure that i fully understand you

Comment: That's not possible with AsyncTask. Like I said, you should declare a instance variable called `ftpClient` in you main activity. Make sure the FtpTask is a inner class, and it should work.

Comment: ok thanks you i did an inner class in MainActivity called FtpTask ,this is what you mean right?