# When I want to open ftp connection the app is crashing

Tags: android

This is an error from the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:289)
at com.liwona_3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is only my code, in onClick()

```
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try {
                ftpClient.connect("server", 21);
                ftpClient.login("username", "pass");
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

I have added permisions for internet acces... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Already answered - The problem is the fact that you're trying to make a network call on your main thread. Which is not allowed on Android 3.0 or higher. - see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12447497/4123144)