# Android: How to connect to FTP Client with onClick?

Tags: java, android, ftp, onclick

I am making an Android app and I am trying to connect to a FTP server (to save an image file) after pressing a 'save' button. The problem is that when it gets to the connecting, the app crashes.

This is the relevant code I am using: 
CameraDemo.java

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // (...)
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient(); //create new FTP
        ftpClient.connect("server",21); //<Here is where it crashes
        ftpClient.login("user","password");
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.logout();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.arjenvangaal.takepicturev2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="nl.arjenvangaal.takepicturev2.CameraDemo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, and how I should edit my code to make it work?

Comment: Have you add the internet permission into manifest.xml?

Comment: Surrounding the code with try/catch blocks and using a logging library like Apache log4j can help you tremendously

Comment: You're trying to make a network call on your main thread. Which is not allowed on Android 3.0 or higher : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12447497/1788704 You have to use an AsyncTask

Comment: Try to remove the port number into .connect(). You created an FTPClient so it should know the port