# I want to access files located on a FTP server and display it in my app

Tags: android, server, ftp, sftp, ftp-client

I want to access files located in a folder on the FTP server by giving ftp's hostname and display it in my app which is developed using the android studio. It should be dynamic, that is it should reflect all the changes done inside the folder of which I have given a specific URL, that is if something is deleted or inserted, it should be reflected in the app. I am unable to connect to FTP server and my app crashes. Below is the code of my app. Please have a look at the code and help me out. 
Thanks.

This is my MainActivity.java:-

```
package com.example.nishant.ftp1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect("ftp.drivehq.com");
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            Log.v("ttt", "connected");
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            /*Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(inStream);
            Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
            int row = s.getRows();
            int col = s.getColumns();

            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for(int c = 0, c< col; c++){
                    Cell z = s.getCell(c, i);
                    String content = z.getContents();
                }
            }*/

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Error in logcat:

```
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 E/Zygote: v2
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SGH-I337_5.0.1-1_0039
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10240
01-24 12:45:09.643 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
01-24 12:45:09.773 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.example.nishant.ftp1-1/base.apk
01-24 12:45:10.013 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-24 12:45:10.253 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-24 12:45:10.664 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-24 12:45:10.674 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.nishant.ftp1, PID: 7023
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nishant.ftp1/com.example.nishant.ftp1.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                         Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:305)
                                                                            at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
                                                                            at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:306)
                                                                            at com.example.nishant.ftp1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
 01-24 12:50:11.007 7023-7023/com.example.nishant.ftp1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7023 SIG: 9
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nishant.ftp1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.6.jar')
}
```

activity_main.xml

Comment: I may be wrong but I think what you need is to look for SMB protocol implementation.

Comment: Please give an example of such an url.

Comment: I want to fetch files from ftp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve the problem by using Asynctask class. You can find code here:

[FTP connection java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446309/ftp-connection-java)

Comment: Thanks, @Amir but I am new to this thing, can you please help me by providing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a method getCurrentFileNames() that get filename and search inside mobile folder and returns a list of Current stored Files.You should also write another method DownloafFileFromServer(String fileName) that takes a file name and  if file exist in server it should download it and if not exist it should delete it in mobile folder.

```
List<String> fileNames = getCurrentFileNames();
String inputfileName;
for(String fileName:fileNames){
if(!inputfileName.equals(fileName){
  DownloadFileFromServer(inputfileName);
  break;
 }
}

public void  DownloadFileFromServer(String fileName){

 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();]
 String url = "http://hostname.com/folder/fileName"
 Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
       client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws 
                  IOException {
                    try {
                      DownloadFileFromUrl(response, fileName);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

}

DownloadFileFromUrl(Response res, String fileName){
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
     File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
      "/folder/" + fileName);
if(res.code == 200){
  try {

        if (f.exists())
            f.delete();
       fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

        is = res.body().byteStream();


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int rd;
        long count = 0;
        while ((rd = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, rd);
            count += rd;



        }
          is.close();
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();


    }
 }
//deleted in server
 else if(res.code == 404){
     if (f.exists())
            //delete in mobile folder as well
            f.delete();

    }

 }
```